# Numbers & escape characters for regex replacement in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to match a pattern using RegEx in notepad++, but not having much luck. I'm able to match part but not all of it.

I need to search for this line:

```
    <size value="Large" pax="13074"/>
```

And replace it with this:

```
    <size value="Very_large" pax="41450"  cargo="Largest" cargovolume="3227"/>
```

Essentially I need to find all patterns matching `pax="n"/>` and replace them with `pax="n" cargo="Largest" cargovolume="0"/>` while retaining the initial value of n.

So, ideas anyone?

Comment: Do you need to replace them with the same `n`?

Comment: Yes, the n value should be retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Ctrl + F, move to tab *Replace*, in *Find what* do: `pax="(\d+)"` and in *Replace with* put this: `pax="\1" cargo="Largest" cargovolume="0"`

Remember to mark regex. That should retain the number and replace the content.

**UPDATE:** Hint about saving text for replacement.

Whenever you use regex to do text replacement, wrap the content you want to save in parenthesis and then you can access them using `\i` where `i` is the order of appearance of the parenthesis starting at 1.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually I noticed I left this behind `/>` in the _Replace with_. That's not necessary because it will duplicate in the answer, you can press Ctrl+Z and remove it :)